# c# fill combox with columns according to a condition

Tags: c#

The code below allows me to show 3 columns from database in a combox, I mean it works fine but when I add a condition to the SQL requete it doesn't show anything.

Here is the condition added:

```cs
void FillData()
{
string constring = (@"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=UnifaceDB;Integrated Security=True");
string Query = "select Code,Module1,Module2,Module3 from prof where Code='" + txtAssignement.Text+"'";
SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
SqlDataReader myReader;
conDataBase.Open();
myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
    {
    string sName = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Module1"));
    comboBox1.Items.Add(sName);
    string sName2 = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Module2"));
    comboBox1.Items.Add(sName2);
    string sName3 = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Module3"));
    comboBox1.Items.Add(sName3);
    }
}
```

The combobox shows as blank when I add a condition with no errors.
My question here is can't I load more than one column in combobox with a condition, if so can someone show me another way.

Comment: Are you sure your txtAssignment.Text value matches a code? You may have leading or trailing spaces in your txtAssignment.Text value or in the database's Code field values.

Comment: What is the value of Query once it is constructed?  Have you tried running the same query directly though management studio?  And also, please paramatise your query.    If not for good coding practice, at least so you don't get bombarded with comments about sql injection

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code slightly, it now uses the *using* block to ensure the data objects get disposed of properly. And uses a SQL Parameter to cleanse the assignment text input and prevent SQL injection attacks. This wasn't needed to fix your problem.

You should verify your *WHERE* clause is set to a valid value used in your database. And one or the other (database or input text) don't contain extra leading or trailing spaces as this could affect your results, depending on your setup.

I setup a test and this code worked for me.

```
    void FillData()
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear(); // clear items before each search

        string constring = (@"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=UnifaceDB;Integrated Security=True");
        string Query = "select Code,Module1,Module2,Module3 from prof where Code=@code"; // command parameter used instead of direct string concatenation

        using (SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase))
            {
                cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", txtAssignement.Text); // apply command parameter
                conDataBase.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        string sName = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Module1"));
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(sName);
                        string sName2 = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Module2"));
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(sName2);
                        string sName3 = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Module3"));
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(sName3);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Somehow it doesn't read the value of txtAssignement, I've tried a code for exemple "GG122" and it did work like this:
`cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", "GG122");`
Btw the txtAssignement is getting a value passed from another form.
Thanks anyway for this input.

Comment: You should lookup how to get a control's value from a different form. Good luck.